# Fetching records(50+) from a table via and sending it to an android application to view it via a listview? Where and how should i start with this?

Tags: android, performance, android-volley

I am a newbie in android development and i have no idea how and where to start with the database access. I also want to use the whole thing with volley library. And also which is the most efficient way to do this other than volley

Comment: use retrofit 2 with listview

Comment: Check this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266783/listview-from-sqlite-in-android